# How to remove property when window is scaled to lower/higher size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, antd

I have a table component here from antd
`<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} scroll={{ x:1000 }} pagination={{pageSize: 4}} />`

Basically I wanted to remove the `scroll={{ x:1000 }}` when I make the browser window bigger, say than `1200px`. How can I achieve this in React?

**Booking function()**

```
function booking() {

    return (

        <div className="booking"> 
            <Navbar bg="" variant="dark" id="mainHeader">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <img
                        src={logo}
                        width="110"
                        height="50"
                        className="d-inline-block align-top ml-4 mt-3 mb-2"
                        alt="logo"
                    />
                </Nav>
                <Nav.Link a href="/" className="ml-sm-4 text-dark">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link a href="/bookings" className=" text-dark">Bookings</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link a href="/signout" className="mr-sm-4 text-dark">Sign Out</Nav.Link>
            </Navbar>

            {/* My Booking Table */}
            <header className="App-header text-dark">
                    <Card border="light" className="bookingCard" id="bookingCard" >
                        <h1 className="mt-4 ml-4" id="cardTitle">Upcoming Bookings</h1>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} {...!!this.state.scroll && { scroll: { x: 1000 }}} pagination={{ pageSize: 4 }} />
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I wanted to change the Table there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event listener, something like that:

```
const threshold = 1200;

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const addScroll = !this.state.addScroll;
    return window.innerWidth >= threshold ^ !addScroll && this.setState({ addScroll });
});
```

And in `render` method:

```
<Table columns={columns}
       dataSource={data}
       {...!!this.state.addScroll && { scroll: { x: 1000 }}
       pagination={{ pageSize: 4 }} />
```

So your full code should look like this:

```
class Booking extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        const widthThreshold = 1200;

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            const addScroll = !this.state.addScroll;
            return window.innerWidth >= widthThreshold ^ !addScroll && this.setState({ addScroll });
        });
    }

    render = () =>
        <div className="booking">
            <Navbar bg="" variant="dark" id="mainHeader">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <img src={logo} width="110" height="50" className="d-inline-block align-top ml-4 mt-3 mb-2" alt="logo"/>
                </Nav>
                <Nav.Link a href="/" className="ml-sm-4 text-dark">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link a href="/bookings" className=" text-dark">Bookings</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link a href="/signout" className="mr-sm-4 text-dark">Sign Out</Nav.Link>
            </Navbar>

            <header className="App-header text-dark">
                <Card border="light" className="bookingCard" id="bookingCard" >
                    <h1 className="mt-4 ml-4" id="cardTitle">Upcoming Bookings</h1>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} {...!!this.state.addScroll && { scroll: { x: 1000 } }} pagination={{ pageSize: 4 }} />
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </header>
        </div>;
}
```

Comment: @rwd Put the listener somewhere inside your component. Share the full code and I can demonstrate it.

Comment: would it be possible to put this into a function instead and call it in the `booking` function i had? instead of creating a `booking` class

Comment: @rwd Of course, you can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263915/how-to-specify-a-constructor-with-a-functional-component-fat-arrow-syntax.
But basically, it is not recommended in such cases, when the component is not stateless.