# React native giving Error when I add constructor(props)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting the following error when I add constructor(props) . What is this error and how can I fix this. Is is because of `export default function LoginForm({navigation}){`

The codes are here:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text,TouchableOpacity,TextInput, ActivityIndicator,Linking } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { sliderStyle } from '../styles/slider';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default function LoginForm({ navigation }){ 
     
     constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            
        }
     }


    const pressHandler = () => {
        navigation.goBack();
    }
     
 
    return (
       <View style={sliderStyle.LoginPageContainer}>
          <Text>Hello React Native!</Text>
       </View>      
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: constructor can be used in a class component not in functional component. You can read answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44264100/3784556

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify a constructor with a functional component (fat arrow syntax)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263915/how-to-specify-a-constructor-with-a-functional-component-fat-arrow-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

a constructor is class-specific and is not available in functional components.
Use useState to initialize state in a functional component.

For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it to export default Class and not Function because a constructor can't be used in a functional component, try this code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Linking,
} from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import { sliderStyle } from "../styles/slider";
import { render } from "react-dom";

//const LoginForm = ({ navigation }) => {
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Linking,
} from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import { sliderStyle } from "../styles/slider";
import { render } from "react-dom";

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {};

  pressHandler = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={sliderStyle.LoginPageContainer}>
        <Text>Hello React Native!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

:

Answer (score -1):

How could you use a `constructor` in a `function`? Just remove the constructor from the `function`. Like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text,TouchableOpacity,TextInput, ActivityIndicator,Linking } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { sliderStyle } from '../styles/slider';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default function LoginForm({ navigation }){ 

    const pressHandler = () => {
        navigation.goBack();
    }
     
 
    return (
       <View style={sliderStyle.LoginPageContainer}>
          <Text>Hello React Native!</Text>
       </View>      
    );
}
```

else use constructor with the class attribute.